# Hyundai Sonata EF (2002 - 2005) - P0335 CKPS Malfunction

Tags: troubleshooting, no-crank-no-start, crank-position-sensor, sonata

Vehicle will not start. I have replaced the CKPS sensor with a used one, but it still brings back the code P0335. before I shell out cash for a brand new sensor. Am I on the right path?

Here are my test results:

Power supply meets specification: **B+**
[image: Power Supply Circuit Inspection]

---

CKPS Power meets specification: 4.98V

[image: CKPS Power Supply Circuit Inspection]

---

Signal Circuit check for short to ground in harness: DMM reads 0.25 ohms
[image: Signal Short to ground in harness]

---

Signal Circuit check for short to battery harness: DMM reads 0.45 ohm

[image: Signal Short to battery harness]

---

Signal Circuit check for open in harness: DMM reads between 0.1 ohms and 0.2 ohms and makes the continuity sound

[image: Signal Circuit open in harness]

---

Ground Circuit Inspection : DMM reads 0.1 ohms and makes the continuity sound

[image: Ground Circuit check for open in harness]

---

I doubt that I have a bad Crankshaft Position Sensor (Crank Angle Sensor)? I also doubt that the PCM is bad. What is the best way to hunt down and eliminate these shorts without tearing out the wiring.

---

Comment: Does the error code appear before you use the starter motor?

Comment: @HandyHowie: Could you rephrase the question? I am not sure that i follow your drift.

Comment: Does the error code appear when you turn the ignition on, or does it only appear when you try to start the engine?

Comment: It does not appear when I turn the ignition on, it only appears after trying to start the engine

Comment: My question is trying to determine whether the engine ECU is immediately detecting the faulty CKPS, or it is noticing that there are no pulses being returned when the engine is turned over.

Comment: In that case, have you checked the physical mounting of the sensor, is it mounted correctly?  Nothing is bent or out of alignment? It is definitely a hall sensor?  Can you see the reluctor ring (the toothed ring that the sensor is near), does it look OK?

Comment: The physical mounting of the sensor is correct, although earlier on I put it the wrong way but figured it out before asking the question. Let me now investigate the reluctor ring and revert

Comment: While I do not have a reference for determining if the reluctor ring is in perfect condition, I am beginning to doubt if it is ok...reason is after watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJ14Zz_1fF8, it seems that It might be responsible for causing the previous sensor to break. Secondly, it seems to be leaning by the sensor

Comment: Does your CKPS and reluctor ring look the same as in that video.  If so, it is worth checking before you spend money on a new CKPS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73186/discussion-between-electronicsnewbie-and-handyhowie).